# nginx with TLS Client Authentication... Error response is not mutual authenticated?

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, ssl-client-authentication, transport-security

I played around with nginx and mutual TLS authentication.
For that i configured the nginx server to actually use client authentication with the config parameter:

```
ssl_verify_client on;
```

It works, but i have a question regarding the termination process.

If i do a get request to e.g. https://localhost and `ssl_verify_client on;` is set, i get an http response even if i don't deliver a valid client certificate:

> 400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent

For me it would make sense that the TLS connection is terminated at the TLS handshake. Why do i get a http response, when the connection is not mutual authenticated?

I also read RFC 5246 and it basically says that it can be done this way (designers choice):

> The TLS standard, however, does not specify how protocols add security
> with TLS; the decisions on how to initiate TLS handshaking and how to
> interpret the authentication certificates exchanged are left to the
> judgment of the designers and implementors of protocols that run on
> top of TLS.

Are there good arguments to do it on the application layer instead of the transport layer?
Is there a possibility to terminate the TLS connection earlier without using a proxy (e.g. HAProxy)?